# C# Exception when "PUT"-ing files on server

Tags: c#, php, nginx, webclient

I'm using a PHP-Script to receive Files via the PUT method as a CLI-Filesharing service. My PHP-Script is fully functional und works with **curl** under linux. Now i tried making a Windows client for it using C# and a WebClient which uploads the File in the Clipboard.

My C# Code is the following: (concatted)

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
byte[] resp = wc.UploadFile(new Uri("https://filec.li/" + Path.GetFileName(f)), "PUT", f);
```

But i get an Exception before it even makes the request:

```
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send
```

nginx access log when accessing with c#(concatted):

```
xxx.xx.xx.xx - - [31/Mar/2016:12:11:50 -0400] "PUT /ani_web.fla HTTP/1.1" 301 209 "-" "-"
```

nginx access log when accessing with curl (concatted):

```
xxx.xx.xx.xx - - [31/Mar/2016:12:32:21 -0400] "PUT /ani_web.fla HTTP/1.1" 200 46 "-" "curl/7.38.0"
```

And the nginx error log is empty.

I also set the **connection timeout to 300 seconds** on the server, aswell as the **max_body_size to 1024M**

I have looked for this all over and I cant seem to find a solution

I forgot to add that the request is SSL

Comment: If you check the HTTP traffic using for example Fiddler, I suspect you'll see that you're getting a redirect on your PUT which will abort it and require a retry on the new URL.

Comment: i may have mis-picked the log, that was when i was accessing the http page, now i am accessing an https page that is why there is a 301

But thanks anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

To the code, i fixed it myself